# vs code highlighting for structs

Tags: struct, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I am using vs code and I have some troubles.

I defined my struct named 'Cod'.

and I made variable, 'Cod a'

but... the color of Cod was just.. white.....

I want to highlight the user-defined structs....

I've tried to find some way by looking for google..

but I didn't find clear way.

is there any ways to do like that?

here is image that I have!

thanks for reading what I write!!!!!!!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlqvE.png)

Comment: What language? I figure that would be helpful in this sort of thing

Comment: Oh sorry! my language is C++!